# SPFieldType of a yes/no (check box) column in a sharepoint list

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint, splist, spfield

I want to know if I added a yes/no (check box) column to my list in my sharepoint website and then let's say in visual studio I wanted to retrieve data from this column what is the equivalent SPFieldType of this column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SPFieldBoolean](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldboolean.aspx) is the field type you're looking for.

Comment: thnx , one more question please: I  want to make an event reciever on item adding to my list and I would like to add his type value to an existing multi choices list so any idea please ?

Comment: Thats a seperate Q Glolita - so ask it as a new question but give a few more details as well.

Comment: I'm trying to create a Yes/No column in VS Community 2015 for O365.  I don't see that type as an available option here : https://koenvosters.wordpress.com/2010/04/27/available-field-types-in-sharepoint-2010/ I know that says 2010, but the Yes/No field exists in 2013/O365.  What do I need to put for "Type"?  Just "Yes/No"